# How to print the iframe content with scrollbar in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

In my application I have placed iframe with scroll bar.Can anybody tell how to take print the content

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if there's only one `iframe` and you didn't assign any name to it; you may simply simply use `window.frames[0]` in place of `window.frames['myname']`)

```
function PrintIframe() { 

    if (window.frames['myname'].innerHTML != "") { 
        window.frames['myname'].focus();
        window.frames['myname'].print();
    } else {
        setTimeout(PrintIframe,1000);
    }    
 }
```